# unable to delete from sql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have designed a url loader for my site, it's working fine but have little problem that it cant delete url at end after loading.

```
<?php
// set time 1000
set_time_limit(1000);

// connect to db
include ("../../config.php"); 

// select data from database target domain and T2 table
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM domain" ) or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error());
$resultx = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM worth" ) or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_query($result);
$num_rowsx = mysql_query($resultx);

// fetching data 
while ($get_infox = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultx) && $get_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $domax="www.".$get_infox[domain];
    $doma=$get_info[domain]; 

    if ($doma != $domax[domain])
    {
        // load urls
        $url="http://www.w3db.org/".$doma."";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $index=curl_exec($ch);
        $error=curl_error($ch); 
        curl_close($ch); 
        // deleting current loaded url
        echo "url loaded and deleted ".$url."<br />";
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM domain WHERE domain=".$doma.""); // problem here
    }
    else
    {
        echo "url skiped and deleted ".$url."<br />";
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM domain WHERE domain=".$doma.""); // problem here
    }
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I do not know why it can't delete, code is ok, no error. I do not know why, please help.

#### For test

Table 1 :: domain having column domain

Table 2 :: T1 having column domain

#### Task

Take url from (table 1) domain, compare with (Table 2) domain url. If not match fetch with curl and then delete, else skip loading url and delete it.

The url is fetched, but it isn't deleted at the end.

Comment: When `mysql_query()` fails, it returns `false`. When it returns `false`, you can use `mysql_error()` to get the last MySQL error codes/messages. What errors are you getting? That will help narrow down your problem. See Example #1 in [the documentation for `mysql_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) for am example of what I mean

Comment: @Thomas just in case you don't know it, this is an incredibly handy tool for commenting on recurring issues like this one: [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](http://stackapps.com/q/2116) I saw your comment and thought that would be worthy of being a comment template in there

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the query fails because `$doma` is a string that's not inside quotes, that is, your query is `... WHERE domain=foo` when it should be `... WHERE domain='foo'`.

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM domain WHERE domain='".$doma."'") or die( mysql_error() );
```

(Remember the `mysql_error()` part, it'll help you debug a lot of issues later on.)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible your query is missing single quotes around $doma ... try this instead ...

```
 "DELETE FROM domain WHERE domain='".$doma."'"

 mysql_query("DELETE FROM domain WHERE domain='".$doma."'"); // problem here
```

assuming $doma is a string ..